# I'm trying to figure out a way to multiply the values of two dictionaries, one of which contains lists

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, dictionary, math

I made the mother of spaghetti code here. This is supposed to multiply the key and/or values two dictionaries (kv1, and kv2), by specifying which (factor1, factor2) and then pruning non-multiplicable results (if pruning is 1) according to what the pruner is (e.g 0 or []).

So here's what I'm trying to do:

1. Figuring out an easier way to assign factor1 and factor2 to their appropriate k1/k2/v1/v2
2. Trying to zip properly since `adsVal` is a dictionary containing lists while valSet is a dictionary containing strings.
3. Trying to multiply the values within each list by their respective string in `valSet` (so value 5 in every list list in `adsVal` would be multiplied by the fifth value of `valSet`)
4. Figuring out how to turn everything that cannot be multiplied (ie any string that cannot be int()) into the pruner (e.g 0) or at least deleting it along with its key

The code is:

```
def multDict(kv1, kv2, factor1, factor2, pruning, pruner):
    # This multiplies something in two dictionaries
    # With pruning on, null values become the pruner
    if factor1 == 'k1':
        factor1 = kv1.keys()
    elif factor1 == 'k2':
        factor1 = kv2.keys()
    elif factor1 == 'v1':
        factor1 = kv1.values()
    elif factor1 == 'v2':
        factor1 = kv2.values()
    if factor2 == 'k1':
        factor2 = kv1.keys()
    elif factor2 == 'k2':
        factor2 = kv2.keys()
    elif factor2 == 'v1':
        factor2 = kv1.values()
    elif factor2 == 'v2':
        factor2 = kv2.values()
    x3 = []
    for x1 in factor1:
        zipped = zip(x1, factor2)
        for y1, x2 in zipped:
            printtxt(x2)
            try:
                int(y1)
                int(x2)
            except:
                pass
            else:
                print(int(y1)*int(x2))
    return x3

print(multDict(adsVal, valSet, 'v1', 'v2', 1, 0))
```

Anything will do, I'm just trying to learn. Thanks.

Sample inputs:

```
adsVal = {'Students': ['inactive', '3'], 'Campaign 1': ['not_delivering', '']}

valSet = {'Delivery': [''], 'Results': ['1000']}
```

Sample output:

```
x3 = {'Students': ['0', '3000'], 'Campaign 1: ['0', '0']
```

Comment: Don't quite get the first part. I think you should split the logic cause if the caller is able to call the method with the right args he should be able to call directly with i.e. `multDict(kv1.values(), kv2.values(), pruning, pruner)`. That said it'll be helpful having an example of input and expected output.

Comment: It would help if you added edited the question to give some same sample inputs and give your expected outputs.

Comment: Done, check it out! :)

Comment: You can save yourself the whole if-elif-construct and change your call to `multDict(adsVal, valSet, adsVal.values(), valSet.values(), 1, 0)` instead of `multDict(adsVal, valSet, 'v1', 'v2', 1, 0)`

Comment: What do you mean by "fifth value of `valSet`"? Dictionaries are inherently unordered, so this changes every execution. You either need a list or an OrderedDict here.

Comment: Note that you don't have to consider `k2`/`v2` for `factor1` since you can just switch the inputs

Comment: @xjcl I wanted to make it easier to use through k1/k2/v1/v2 instead of the .key() .values() thingies.

Also I know dictionaries are unordered but I thought that if two dictionaries came from the same ordered list they would remain ordered :S

Also why don't I have to consider `k2/v2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import collections

def mul_maybe_ints(a, b, pruner=None):
    try:
        return int(a)*int(b)
    except ValueError:
        return pruner

def strings_times_strings(aa, ab, pruner=None):
    return [mul_maybe_ints(a, b, pruner) for a,b in zip(aa,ab)]

def lists_times_strings(aa, sa, pruner=None):
    return [[mul_maybe_ints(el, s, pruner) for el in a] for a,s in zip(aa,sa)]


# example usage
adsVal = collections.OrderedDict()
adsVal['Students'] = ['inactive', '3']
adsVal['1'] = ['not_delivering', '']

valDict = collections.OrderedDict()
valDict['Delivery'] = '50'
valDict['Results'] = '1000'

result = lists_times_strings(adsVal.values(), valDict.values(), 0)
print( result )  # [[0, 150], [0, 0]]
print( { k : v for k,v in zip(adsVal, result) } )  # {'Students': [0, 150], '1': [0, 0]}

print( strings_times_strings(adsVal.keys(), valDict.values(), 0) )  # [0, 1000]
```

Some considerations:

- It's still not entirely clear to me what you specifically want to do
- As I said in the comments, a dictionary doesn't have a "fifth" element as it is unordered, which is why I use an `OrderedDict`
- I always prune since multiplying two non-integers isn't a defined operation
- This gives you only lists back, so you have to build the dictionary at the call site (see example, you could wrap this into its own function too)

Comment: Thanks! I'll keep trying this one out until I figure out what you did. By the way, I've been looking into matrices. Would they be useful for doing things like these?

Comment: Using matrices eg in `numpy` has two principal advantages: (1) You can eg write 3*v where v is a vector to multiply 3 with each element and (2) these can be a lot faster since large parts of `numpy` are implented in C. *However* since you have strings in there I'm not sure they are the appropriate data model for what you're trying to do. Also it isn't worth it if you don't do a lot of numerical operations on the data.

Comment: I plan to get a lot of elements containing other elements, each one with a numeric value. So there'd be element A, which contains elements A1, A2, A3, whereas A1 has the value 10, A2 has the value 1 and A3 has the value 5. And I would do things such as adding them up to figure out the total of A. Or add the values of A1, B1, C1 etc. and then get the average of those. And so on. So I need a very flexible framework, which is why I considered matrices. Does that sound like a good idea?